# Is it possible to migrate a bootable NVMe SSD to a different one via a dd image?

Tags: linux, ssd, dd, nvme

I have a Linux Mint installation on a M.2 NVMe SSD in a laptop.
I'd like to move this installation to a new laptop with a fresh SSD.

Is it possible to create an image using `dd` on the old laptop and `dd` it back to the SSD on the new laptop?
Or will this cause boot problems, for example caused by the different UUIDs of the SSDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part this should work fine.  Linux is a lot more tolerant of differences in hardware the Windows.  The UUID will stay the same as it follows the partition rather then the hardware.

Where you may experience a difficulty might be in the boot process.  If you are using Legacy boot mode you should be OK, but if you are using UEFI the new computer may not know to boot Linux.  You will likely need to USB Boot and then fix UEFI - https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-efi-boot-manager-entries-on-linux

Comment: The old laptop is already an UEFI system. So I definitely need to work with efibootmgr on a live USB stick after dd'ing the image to the new SSD?

Comment: Try and then cross that bridge only if needed.